# Reading property file data from a servlet

Tags: multithreading, servlets, jakarta-ee, web, file-io

I am working on a web application, in which I am reading some configuration data stored in xml file from a Servlet. I want the data read from this servlet available to all the requests coming to this servlet. So inside the init() method of this servlet I am initializing global variable , which will have content read from this xml file so that all the request coming to this servlet will have this data available and don't have to read from the xml file again and again.

My first question is, is this method is better way to share data among request coming only to this servlet. I don't want to share it across all the servlets.

Comment: Asking questions works better if you ask one question per question.

Comment: @BalusC Edited the question as per your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule here is just locality: if that data is only used by one single servlet, it should be local to the servlet, meaning as per you proposal:

- a member of the servlet class
- loaded in the `init` method of the servlet

But (as your initial post asked), if that data can be updated *by another servlet of the same web application*, it make sense to move it one step up to a SerletContext attribute. That way:

- it can still be initially loaded in the `init` method of the servlet
- it can be changed at any time by any other component of the web application that knows the name of the attribute.

You can imagine plenty of other ways, by using for example custom events and using an observable pattern, or by mapping the servlet to a special (and private) URL that would signal that the xml file must be reloaded, but IMHO, a servlet context attribute is a clean and simple way to allow different servlet to exchange informations.

But **beware**, you will still need an extra synchronization mechanisme if your web application is intended to be served by more than one single server

Comment: exactly what i was looking. great!